# Realize 1000 samples of not i.i.d normally distributed variables in R

Tags: r, statistics

I want to generate 1000 samples of X_1...._1000 in R where it is known that 
X_t
=0.9*_(t−1)+ error, where the errors are IID standard normally distributed, and that 1 is (0,100/19)
I have shown that each  has the distribution (0,100/19)and that they are not independent.

How does one generate this sample realization in R?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I wanted to use rnorm(1000,0,100/19) but this would give me 1000 i.i.d realisations right?

Comment: Yes, those would be independent.

Comment: yeah so that wouldn't help

Comment: You got a *very*  relevant comment under this cross-post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/435552/generate-dependent-normally-distributed-realizations-in-r

Answer (score 0):

You do not say how big the standard deviation for the error should be, so I made an arbitrary choice. Just generate your data sequentially using the formula that you gave.

```
set.seed(2019)
x = rep(0,1000)
ErrorSD = 0.1
x[1] = rnorm(1,0,100/19)
for(i in 2:1000) { 
    x[i] = 0.9*x[i-1] + rnorm(1,0,ErrorSD) }
plot(x, type='l')
```

[image: Time Series]